# With Firestore, what's the best way to save and retrieve a lot of dates?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating an app that tracks daily goals. Each day that a user reaches their "goal" I need to save the current date to firestore. What would be the best approach to saving dates to firestore? Currently this is the setup I have:

[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pJE4.png)

However, the problem with this setup is when I try to retrieve/update/remove fields under a users' document, I get the following [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaIrV.png).

Would I want to use Unix time for this and do conversions in swift, or is there another way of referencing fields with "/" in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing dates and times as strings is not really a good idea.  You should probably be using the timestamp type for fields that contain dates and times.

Firestore has a native type for dates and times [as documented here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types).   You can read and write those values using the [Timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/Timestamp) class.  If you  just need the date and not the time, set all the time components to 0.

Comment: Good to know. Also for referencing purposes, do you think I should save the field names as the time stamp and set it = true or is there a better way of doing that?

Comment: How you actually structure your data is highly dependent on how you need to query your data.  There is no "right way", just the way that suits your queries.

Comment: I am going to want to query all of users' dates at once when I create a calendar that will display all the days the user has accomplished their goal. Will I want to save all these dates in an array or an object? Or just as separate fields in a document? Which will be easiest for me to retrieve and query all dates at once?

Comment: If you have a different question about data modeling, that should be its own question.